# Removing Wysiwyg filter form from a node field in edit form in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor, wysiwyg, field

I need to remove the wysiwyg filter format for a textarea field. This field belongs to a content-type and should not allow the editors to put data using wysiwyg.

So, basically i need to remove the wysiwyg option from the drop down that appears for a textarea on the node/edit page.

I am using ckeditor as a plugin for wysiwyg module.

Please help me solving this.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way (that I know of) to do it in the UI but you can make a custom module and implement `hook_form_alter()` very easily:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'the_form_id') {
    $form['field_name']['und'][0]['#wysiwyg'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Clive,

I tried the same, but doesn't seem to be working in drupal7. Can you suggest any other approach.

Thanks

Comment: @PiyueshKumar Have you tried clearing the cache since you put the function in your code?